# How to create a subscription to SNS using filter policy in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Can you please help me? I'm trying to create a subscription to SNS via code using filter policy in .net. My topic has the following Subscription filter policy (using MessageAttribute):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkKBp.png)

I tried configure as follow:

```
public async Task CreateSubscriptionAsync()
    {
        using var snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(_amazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig);

        _ = await snsClient.SubscribeAsync(new SubscribeRequest
        {
            Protocol = "sqs",
            Endpoint = _sqsSettings.Queues!.First(queue => !queue.Consume).Url,
            TopicArn = _snsSettings.Topic!.Arn,
            Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "MessageType", "OrderReceived" } }
        });
    }
```

But I received the following error:

Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model.InvalidParameterException : AttributeName.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Done folks, follow the answer:

```
public async Task CreateSubscriptionAsync()
    {
        using var snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(_amazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig);

        _ = await snsClient.SubscribeAsync(new SubscribeRequest
        {
            Protocol = "sqs",
            Endpoint = _sqsSettings.Queues!.First(queue => !queue.Consume).Url,
            TopicArn = _snsSettings.Topic!.Arn,
            Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "FilterPolicy", "{\"MessageType\":[\"OrderReceived\"]}" } }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?